# В "винтажЕ" или "в винтАже" - Как правильно поставить ударение?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно поставить ударение- в винтажЕ или в винтАже?

Answer (score 1):

винта́ж, -а, тв. -ем
Яндекс.Словари › Орфографический словарь. — 2004

Получается,  "в винтАже".

Comment: А почему отличается например от "гарАж/гаражЕ"?

Comment: В русском языке ударение во многих словах подвижное, поэтому стоит доверять авторитетным словарям. В том же словаре статья:  гара́ж, -а́, тв. -о́м
Яндекс.Словари › Орфографический словарь. — 2004